# Template in C++ .. Printing wrong output

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

I can't figure it out .... My code is not printing anything. Do I need to create a different node or Am I writing the wrong code? Please help. An explanation will be much appreciated. Code can only go where it says "Start here // End here. Anything outside cant be modified.

Expected answer:

```
one->eins
two->zwei
three->drei
four->vier
five->funf
one
three
zwei
funf
one->1
two->2
three->3
four->4
five->5
one
three
2
5
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//The class my_pair which stores two values of different types referred to as value1 and value2

//Your code starts here
template <class T, class U>
//Your code ends here
class my_pair
{
    //Your code starts here
    T value1;
    U value2;
    //Your code ends here

public:
    //Your code starts here
    my_pair(T value1, U value2)
    {
        value1 = this->value1;
        value2 = this->value2;
    }
    //Your code ends here

    T get_value1()
    {
        return this->value1;
    }
    U get_value2()
    {
        return this->value2;
    }
};

            
//The class node implements a linked list of pairs
template <class T, class U>
class node
{
    my_pair<T, U>* value;
    node* next;

public:
    //Creates a new node
    node(T value1, U value2)
    {
        //Your code starts here
        this->value = new my_pair<T, U>(value1, value2);
        this->next = nullptr;
        //Your code ends here
    }
    //Add a new pair at the end of the list
    void add(T value1, U value2)
    {
        //Your code starts here
        if (this->next == nullptr) this->next = new node(value1, value2);
        this->next = nullptr;
        //Your code ends here
    }
    //Find the value2 corresponding to the value1 passed as parameter
    T find_value1(U value2)
    {
        //Your code starts here
        node* curr = this;
        while (curr != nullptr)
        {
            if (curr->value->get_value2() == value2) 
                return curr->value->get_value1();
            curr->next = nullptr;
        }
        return 0;
        //Your code ends here
    }
    //Find the value1 corresponding to the value2 passed as parameter
    U find_value2(T value1)
    {
        //Your code starts here
        node* current = this;
        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            if (current->value->get_value1() == value1)
                return current->value->get_value2();
            current->next = nullptr;
        }
        return 0;
        //Your code ends here
    }

    void print()
    {
        node* curr = this;
        while (curr != nullptr)
        {
            cout << curr->value->get_value1() << "->" << curr->value->get_value2() << endl;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
};

//After

int main()
{
    node<int, string>* dictionary = new node<int, string>(1, "one");
    dictionary->add(2, "two");
    dictionary->add(3, "three");
    dictionary->add(4, "four");
    dictionary->print();
    cout << endl;
    cout << dictionary->find_value1("one") << endl;
    cout << dictionary->find_value2(4) << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin.get();

    node<string, string>* dictionary2 = new node<string, string>("uno", "one");
    dictionary2->add("dos", "two");
    dictionary2->add("tres", "three");
    dictionary2->add("cuatro", "four");
    dictionary2->print();
    cout << endl;
    cout << dictionary2->find_value2("uno") << endl;
    cout << dictionary2->find_value1("cuatro") << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in a debugger to find out how it's operating?

Comment: Yes, but my output is 0->

Comment: This is a lot of code to review, so you should at least be able to figure out the general idea of why it's getting stuck.

Comment: In function `void add(T value1, U value2)`, why do you set `next` to `nullptr` after adding?
Same in your `find_value` functions.
Another one: in your `my_pair` constructor the values or mixed (prefer init list in constructor and avoid same names for func params and class var).

Comment: wonder if we can close function prematurely (inside `//Your code starts here` `//Your code ends here`) to create other function to respect rule of 5 ;-)

Comment: `return 0;` for "not found" might be problematic for some types. `throw` seems the best alternative according to signatures.

Answer (score 0):

A few things of note:

1. Whenever you call `add`, you're assigning `nullptr` to `next`, undoing what the first line of the function did.
2. Since the main code calls `add` on the same (first) node, and not the newly added node, the current `add` routine (if you remove the `nullptr` assignment) will only ever end up with 2 nodes in your list. You'll have to find a way to traverse the list and find the last node, and add to that one.
3. Your `find_valueN` is stuck in an infinite loop. It will keep repeating as long as `current` exists, but you don't have anything that changes `current`. You do have a line that changes `current->next`, but that's not going to help you. (In fact, that's going to ruin the data you're looking at. Be careful of modifying data when you're only supposed to be looking at it.) What you should do instead, is change that line to make `current` become the value held in `current->next`. Don't change anything inside `current`. Look at the bottom of the `print` function for an example.

Looks alright otherwise. Well done with the template definition. :-)

Comment: 3. `const node* curr = this` might help. Sad that surrounding code which should not be modified has some "mistakes".

Comment: I agree. I was going to mention const-ness, but I figure this is part of a course, and const-ness hasn't been introduced yet.